# Is there a simple UI hack to auto-hide the menu, but keep the menubar?

Tags: menu-bar

I never use the menu items but I'd like to put more icons in the menubar itself.

The (application contextual) menu items are useless to me without keyboard navigation, but they take half of the menubar, I'd love to just get rid of them.

I'm wondering if there's a simple hack to get rid of all the menu items except for the apple icon (and maybe the current app name)?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it - but what do you mean 'without keyboard navigation'? Ctrl/F2 will start menu navigation.

Comment: There's no way of opening a specific menu directly, it takes way too long with that shortcut, while the navigation inside a menu is decent, it is not geared for keyboard users, so it can take a while to get to menu items that are weirdly named. So I could be staring directly at some text label, and I have to type a bunch of letters to get to it and if there are multiple that are similarly named it becomes awfully tiresome and sometimes impossible. So I end up hitting down arrow for a long time.

Comment: True, though I never use it on Windows either. I just learn the key commands ;)

Comment: That's why I want to hide the entire menu, it's pointless for me to see all the entries if it's impossible to use them with the keyboard directly, Ctrl+F2 (or clicking) should bring it back from auto-hide. Auto-hiding them frees up so much space that is currently wasted

Comment: If you go to full-screen mode ( green button top left) the app will expand to full screen and hide the menu bar. and dock  Putting the cursor all the way to the top or bottom temporarily displays the menu bar or dock.  Click the green button again to return to regular mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, and it's free :)

I asked this same question on reddit a few months ago and the amazing @w0lfchild (dev of mySimbl) created it!

https://github.com/w0lfschild/moreMenu

> [image]

Comment: I did find it a while back, but I couldn't get it to work. It gave weird messages that it needs to install some other plugins. Maybe I wasn't persistent enough, the OS started asking me security questions about each app and I never fully restarted all apps like it asked.

Comment: yeah it needs some autorizations and the apps to be restarted to work properly, after that it'll work 95% of the time (except for rare apps that use a different mechanisms to handle their menu); but overall it is quite amazing to have that space available at all times.

Answer (score -1):

Check the app Bartender. Also, for most Apps you can disable the menubar icon if you check the preferences.

Comment: My biggest gripe is not managing the icons (in fact I want more), it's the textual menu items. I tried Bartender, but I couldn't find any setting to hide the menu (even though it's not visible in the screenshots on their website)

Comment: OP is specifically looking to hide textual menu items. No, Bartender only hides the menubar icons (right hand stuff) not the textual menus (left hand stuff near apple logo). None of the apps I use allow to hide their textual menus in the menu bar.

Comment: There is a 3rd party app Vanilla (https://matthewpalmer.net/vanilla/) which claims to do what you want.  There is a free version that didn't seem to do much and a $5 pro version.  Maybe I'm just using it wrong.  Caveat emptor